# Bash script string interpolation leaves curly braces intact

Tags: bash, shell-script

The request string in the example below interpolates version variable, but keeps the curly braces and I can't figure out why.

```
#!/bin/sh

version=2989
request="http://example.com/?version={$version}&therest"
echo "$request"
```

Result:

```
$ ~/script.sh
http://example.com/?version={2989}&therest
```

Environment:

```
$ echo $0
-zsh
```

Comment: You don't run bash in your example, you run sh.

Comment: You have the parenthesis inside a quoted string, so they are output literally. Only `$version` is replaced, because variable expansion is one the things which does get performed within double-quoted strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{` is before `$`.  It should be `${version}` :)

Answer (score 1):

Compare:

```
$ version=1.2; echo "http://example.com/?version={$version}&therest"
http://example.com/?version={1.2}&therest
$ version=1.2; echo "http://example.com/?version=${version}&therest"
http://example.com/?version=1.2&therest
```

Inside quoted, braces are regarded as just normal characters unless they are part of some construct like `${variableName}`.